# json dumps & loads issues

Tags: python, json, memory, serialization, load

So in Python I'm trying to dump 2 things into memory using `json` (a dictionary and a list of lists). I'm then trying to load them for processing.

I don't think I want to dump as `string` type as then I'd lose functionality such as `myList[0]` would show the first character, rather than the object at the first index (assuming 1D list).

I'm receiving the error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'BufferedReader'
```

The error is found in the load methods, the dump methods seem to be okay. The particular line error I'm being shown is that in `return json.loads(cdFP)` `json.loads` doesn't want to take the `cdFP` variable.

Please see code below:

```
def pickleDumpDia():
    with open("./PickleDumpDia", 'wb') as fp:
        output = json.dumps(createDocInfoArrays("application.tsv"), fp)
    return output

def pickleDumpCd():
    with open("./PickleDumpCd", 'wb') as fp:
        output = json.dumps(createSameTSVDateDict("uspatentcitation.tsv"), fp)
    return output

def loadDocDateArray():
    with open("./PickleDumpDia","rb")as diaFP:
        output = json.loads(diaFP)
    return output

def loadCitationDict():
    with open("./PickleDumpCd","rb") as cdFP:
        return json.loads(cdFP)
```

Comment: Try converting the bytes to a string by adding <var>.decode("utf-8") to the bytes-string

Comment: Use `json.load` to load JSON data from a file, use `json.loads` to load from a string.

Comment: @user508402 Just so I understand - what I'm dumping (aka createSameTSVDateDict("uspatentcitation.tsv")) needs to be converted, or the input to the json.load() method needs to be converted?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the response, so as I want to retain dictionary functionality I must save as JSON data rather than string? Or am I misunderstanding here? When I change to .load I receive the error "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'"

Comment: Open the JSON files as text not binary. You may also need to pass UTF8 as the encoding.

Comment: Just converting the input string should do.

Comment: @PM2Ring If I open the JSON files as text do I lose the dictionary functionality? Thanks

Comment: Issue resolved by using dump/dump/load/load - thanks for all of your help!